# Issue with opening angular docx file

Tags: angular, docx

[image: word Error]I am using angular docx for export to docx file. but for some files which have large data it opens like this[image]

Even in word it is getting error.
please solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: If Word is not able to open it, I'm not sure how an angular plugin is supposed to open it? It does seem like an issue with the file itself and not with the plugin. Did you try rendering any other files?

Comment: yes, other files are opening which has less data in it

Comment: What about files with large data? Do they open in Word?

Comment: No, larges files was not opening in word, as well as libreOffice

Comment: This means that issue is with the files and not Word / angular plugin

Comment: so, is there any solution to open that large files normally with code?

Comment: Which library are you using exactly ? I couldn't find anything similar to "angular-docx"

Comment: This is the library- https://docx.js.org/api/